# PHP time() returns a timestamp that is 59 seconds behind real time

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-7.0

I have a dev environment and a production environment. The time() function returns the correct timestamp in my dev env but in my production environment time() is exactly 59 seconds behind!
The version of PHP is 7.0.3 on both environments.
This can't be a timezone issue since the difference is only one minute and the PHP default timezone is the same in both environments (America/Los Angeles).
It is now 10:48:29 am and here is the output from calling this function simultaneously in both environments (or at least as fast as I can press enter on the console).

**Dev environment (is correct)**

```
php > echo date('h:i:s A');
10:48:29 AM
```

**Production environment (is one minute behind)**

```
echo date('h:i:s A');
10:47:31 AM
```

Same happens with the time() function

**Dev environment (is correct)**

```
php > echo time();
1568742851
```

**Production environment (is one minute behind)**

```
echo time();
1568742792
```

And **1568742851 - 1568742792 = 59 secs**

I know i could just add 59 seconds to the timestamp time() returns but that just seems like a hack and does not solve the problem. I would like to please get advice as to how to fix my production environment.

Comment: Is it possible that one one of the system the system clock does not show the correct time?

Comment: What do you mean with dev and production environment? Are those two different OS, PC, VMs, ...? If so are you sure that those have the same time in seconds?

Comment: Environments are are in different servers but same OS and PHP version. @g_bor the production env does have a different OS-level system timezone is set to UTC. Which is a 9 hour difference not just a minute so do you think this might cause PHP to miscalculate the UNIX epoc???

Comment: No, I do not believe that. What I think is that the time one one of the systems might be off by 59 seconds. Do you have an independent mean to ask the system what it thinks it is? Like running date in a tty?

Comment: Yes I run the unix command timedatectl and that shows the system time which is in UTC in production. When I run the php time() function is when it shows just 59 seconds behind which is very strange!

Comment: Is the PHP part (where you run `echo time()`) actually in a VM, or some other isolation, inside the production machine (where you run `datetimectl`)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the production machine and the development machine are two separate physical machines. I have two command lines and two separate ssh sessions for each where I'm running time() functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that you are allowing NTP traffic to your production OS environment. You can confirm that your server is properly communicating to NTP by running the following command `ntpq -c peers` If you receive a `Connection refused` prompt you don't have proper connectivity. You will need to configure an inbound firewall rule allowing UDP traffic on port 123. Once this is done, restart your NTP service `service ntpd restart` and rerun the `ntpq -c peers` command

Comment: It was definitely a NTP communication issue and this totally solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system clock on your production and dev machine is unsync, Regardless of the version of PHP or Operating System, Just like @g_bor mentioned in comment.

Don't get confused by the time zone, Just run the command `date +%s` on system shell to print timestamp on both machines, If you have no permission (can't login with ssh), You can prepare the PHP file which contains `system('date +%s');`, And then, Upload to your web server and open the browser to check the timestamps on both your machines.